# Infragistics - disable ultrawingrid automatically updating when datasource changes

Tags: vb.net, infragistics

I have a wingrid that is bound to a datatable.  I create a new asynchronous thread and from that thread make a remote server call passing the datatable.  When the server call is completed the wingrid automatically refreshes to show any changes.  However, since this is not being done on the main UI thread of the program, we will often get an error where the control goes whilte and a big red X appears in it.

Is there a flag to set the wingrid to not automatically upate when the datasource changes?  I would like to turn it off before the remote server call and turn it on again after I am back on the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use

```
Grid1.BeginUpdate()
```

before the asynchronous method. This methods prevents the grid from painting.  Then use

```
Grid1.EndUpdate()
```

on the UI thread once the asynchronous method was done.

Comment: This only prevents painting.  The best approach is to always update the DataTable on the UI thread as there isn't any way to prevent the grid or any bound control from receiving notifications and this is still updating the control from a background thread which can cause problems as there are only a few members of Control which are thread safe.  See the Thread Safety section of Control on MSDN for more details on thread safety: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx

Comment: also free library like `PostSharp` could help with its `[ThreadSafeMethod]` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
Grid1.SuspendRowSynchronization()
```

then, when done:

```
Grid1.ResumeRowSynchronization()
```

Comment: That did not work.  I added & updated rows in the datatable and the grid still showed the changes

Comment: That is very strange. According to the Infragistics documentation (http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridBase~SuspendRowSynchronization.html), this shouldn't happen. It sounds like a possible bug in the control.